# How to trigger a batch script if the service is stopped?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a service named "Aveva RULES Server" on a windows server. This service is frequently going down and causing a lot of business impact across globe. Is there a script which checks this service every 5-10minutes and start the service if it is stopped.

Comment: This site is not a free script writing or interactive metasearch service. Your request is off-topic. _If your global business is being impacted so much, perhaps the cost of a programmer would be a worthwhile investment_.

Comment: Services are managed. Use `services.msc` (GUI) to set recovery action in case of failure.

Comment: I would also assume that when the service goes down, a log entry is created which Windows Event Views can see. A Windows Task Scheduler task can be created to watch for specific event numbers and trigger something to execute when it sees that event.